# Significance of variance components in Stata output

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis

This might be trivial, but I'm used to HLM7 software output and now I'm switching to Stata (`xtmixed`).

To give an example imagine I have students (level-1) nested within schools (level-2).
Running an empty model, in HLM, I can easily see the variance component associated to each level, to see how much variation is at level-1 and how much is at level-2.
Starting from that, I also calculate the intra-class correlation coefficient.

Now I see the variance components, in the `xtmixed` output, these are reported as the standard deviation estimates of the intercept `sd(_cons)` and of the residuals `sd(Residual)`.
How do I calculate the associated p-value to see if there is significance?

Comment: Well, this is probably because you shouldn't look at these p-values, Stata knows that and this is why doesn't show anything there. Look at this discussion http://statalist.1588530.n2.nabble.com/st-How-to-get-the-P-values-of-the-random-effects-after-running-an-xtmixed-command-td3392647.html

Comment: Thanks. Can you better explain here also so we have an answer here? Moreover, how do I calculate the p-value even if not totally accepted as valid?

Comment: Your thoughts on that issue have been discussed in CV before. For your specific question I couldn't give an answer. Look the answers in this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4858/how-to-test-random-effects-in-a-multilevel-model-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the display of the results, specify the option `variance` if you prefer variances over standard deviations.

Concerning the significance, you can run an OLS of the dependent variable on all independent variables with exception of the level 2 identifier (i.e. schools), using the command `regress`.
Store the estimates you obtain through `estimates store` [name1].

Then estimate your multilevel model using `xtmixed` and again store the estimates by `estimates store` [name2].

The difference between these models is the random intercept you allowed in the multilevel estimation but not in the OLS estimation; hence testing whether the unconstrained model performs better is equivalent to testing significance of the random intercept.
`lrtest` [name1] [name2]`, force` will do this for you. You will need to specify the `force` option; otherwise Stata deems the test invalid.